# ASP.NET check on thread status on long running thread?

Tags: .net, asp.net, multithreading

I have a situation where user requests to do a long running process.  I planing to start it on another thread in code-behind and return message to user "processing". Then every couple of seconds or so I will poll(via asynch call) the thread for its status.  When thread is done I want to show success message.

Question, how do I poll a thread once the original request is complete?

As far as I understand, Page object will spin off a separate thread. When request is complete, the Page object is no longer there...but what about that thread? How do I get the status of that thread that I created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you'll need *some* way of identifying the request. If you want to be able to scale this out to multiple machines, you should look at storing the request ID and current status in a database (or some similarly accessible-from-anywhere storage).

If you don't care about that situation *and* you're not worried about AppDomain recycling, you could just have a singleton dictionary from request ID to status - but consider making it automatically flush itself after some period if the client just goes away and doesn't check the status.

(Of course it doesn't have to be a true singleton - it could be some shared resource provided with dependency injection, but the point is it needs to be shared *somehow* so you can get at it from the new request.)

You could also potentially use a session-backed object - again with caveats about multi-server web sites and `AppDomain` recycling.

Comment: so, i create a singleton class that stores (request id, status) on original request. then the thread is going to update the status by using that singleton class. then on any subsequent request I can check status via that singleton class. is that correct?

Comment: The singleton would store a collection of "current request, status" yes. But you may well be better off just going for a session object, thinking about it. All that does is treat the session container in the framework as the singleton - it's exactly the same principle. You'll be able to see what's going on more clearly using your own container though.

Comment: as far as clean up, i can remove the the "current request, status" pair from session when user requests status and when status is "done". however, i'll still need a way to handle situation where user does not request for status (leaves or closes page). is there a standard way to do that clean up?

Comment: Well, if the session has a timeout associated with it, then the whole session will be removed after that period, I'd imagine. I'm not an ASP.NET expert though.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with Jon's answer. You don't need a way of identifying the request, you need a way of uniquely identifying the thread that your request created. Then your ajax request to poll the thread can check if the Thread is finished execution. I don't see why the original request is at all relevant...